# How do I make a div have a margin, but others not?

Tags: html, margin

I made a div called navbar that has no margins by styling the body as following:

```
body {
margin: 0;
}
```

But now I want to create a div that doesn't have a margin under the navbar. How do I make one div with no margin, and one with?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 2 divs inside the body:

```
<body>
   <div id="div1"></div>
   <div id="div2"></div>
</body>
```

your css:

```
body {
margin: 0;
}

#div1 {margin:0}
#div2 {margin:5px}//or auto or whatever
```

You can target specific elements by assigning ids to them (or classes).

Your question is a bit confusing since you set 0 margin to the body. 0 = no margin as far as I understand. 
However, the rules I've mentioned will help you easily tackle this problem.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
   margin: 0;
}
```

In your code above, it just gives the body a margin of 0. It does not give all the elements in your page a margin of 0. It seems like that's what you thought it would do. If you wanted to give all elements, `body, p, ul, li, h1, etc` a margin of 0 it would be written like this

```
* {
   margin: 0;
}
```

the `*` is a universal selector.

There are many ways to give margins to elements.

Lets say you have the following html:

```
<header id="header">
    <div class="nav">
       <ul>
         <li>Menuitem1</li>

         <li>Menuitem2</li>

         <li>Menuitem3</li>

         <li>Menuitem4</li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </header>
```

You could give a margin to all the nav menu li's by

```
.nav li {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

This would give a margin of 10px to all sides of the li. Top, right, bottom and left.

This example below would give a margin of 0 to the top and bottom, but a margin of 5px to right and left sides.

```
.nav li {
    margin: 0 5px;
}
```

This example below would give a margin of 8px just to the right side.

```
.nav li {
    margin: 0 8px 0 0;
}
```

Now lets say you wanted to give a bottom margin to the header.

```
header {
    margin: 0 0 50px 0;
}
```

You can also use %'s for margins to make them responsive.

```
header {
    margin: 0 0 10% 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One option would be to assign the css on an id and not on a tag